# How do I add calabash-ios sim location to script?

Tags: ios, ruby, calabash

I am presently trying to touch a button on a calendar popup.  I understand that as it is a new window I need first acknowledge that I am looking at it, and not the window below the popover.

So I see that I am supposed to use the command;

```
calabash-ios sim location on <bundleid>
```

However when I add something even remote to that in my steps.rb file I get an error...

```
features/step_definitions/steps.rb:84: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting keyword_do or '{' or '(' (SyntaxError)
```

How and where do I insert this command so it will not throw a syntax error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, it's a waiting game for popovers.

This is answered here...

[How do I definitively touch a button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14690315/how-do-i-definitively-touch-a-button?rq=1)